# Trying to add tag around quotes (regex?)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying using regex to add a specific tag to a quoted string, like this :

```
Hey i am a 'quoted' bro
```

The this is that I would like it to become like this :

```
Hey i am a <i>'quoted'</i> bro
```

So that it keeps the quotes and also adds the tag.
Tried to do it with regex but unable to achieve anything ...

This is one of the things I tried to do :

```
quotes = html.match(/'/g);
 for(i = 0; j,quotes.length; j++) {
    if(j%2 == 0){
  //and here I wanted to replace the matched stuff but can't do it
 }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace()` approach:

```js
var str = "{ hostname: 'google.com', path : '/', method: 'POST'",
    replaced = str.replace(/'([^']+)'/g, function (m0, m1) {
        return "<i>" + m1 + "</i>";
    });

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, if I have an unknown number of quotes inside my string, is that possible to make it automatically ? Without using the $1 I mean

Comment: ok, show the extended example with that  *unknown number of quotes*

Comment: Something like a JSON for example:
`{ hostname: 'google.com', path : '/', method: 'POST'` etc.